# Working with Twitter OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (User Context)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to play with the twitter API using tweepy.

This is my code:

```
oauth2_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth2UserHandler(
    client_id=client_id,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope=scopes,
    client_secret=client_secret,
)

auth_url = oauth2_user_handler.get_authorization_url()

print('Please authorize this application: {}'.format(auth_url))

verifier = input('Enter the authorization response URL:')
token = oauth2_user_handler.fetch_token(verifier)
client = tweepy.Client(access_token=token['access_token'])
user = client.get_me(user_auth=False)
```

On the last line I'm getting this error:

> Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Application-Only is forbidden for this
> endpoint.  Supported authentication types are [OAuth 1.0a User
> Context, OAuth 2.0 User Context]

So, it's telling me that I'm using OAuth 2.0 **Application-Only**, but everything I read says that this is how you get a **user** access token using OAuth 2.0 **User Context**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74331503/tweepy-get-me-error-when-using-oauth-2-0-user-auth-flow-with-pkce) answer helped me and got me to this point, but I can't pass that error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in my code in this line:

```
client = tweepy.Client(access_token=token['access_token'])
```

it should be:

```
client = tweepy.Client(token['access_token'])
```